# Any way to access function installed by makeActiveBinding?

Tags: r, scoping

The title basically says it all.

If I do this ...

```
makeActiveBinding("x", function() runif(2), .GlobalEnv)
x
# [1] 0.7332872 0.4707796
x
# [1] 0.5500310 0.5013099
```

... is there then any way for me to examine `x` to learn what function it is linked to (and if not, why not)?

(In this case, I'd like to be able to learn that `x` was defined to be `function() runif(2)`.)

Comment: Romain Francois suggested a [patch to R-devel in 2009](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-June/053899.html) to modify this behaviour ([see the link to attachment with C code](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/attachments/20090629/16a8c41a/attachment.pl))

Comment: @Andrie this patch did not give the binding function, just print that this is indeed an active binding

Comment: @Andrie Interesting, but IIUC, it still looks like all Romain's patch would do for `str(x)` would be to print (or rather `cat()`) the string "<active binding>\n". Is that what you see too?

Comment: @RomainFrancois -- Is it your understanding that, short of C-level hacking, the details of the active binding (including the R function it references) are hidden? Is what I'm asking for similar, in its impossibility, to wanting to see the internals of a promise object? (Meaning is it hidden, on purpose?)

Comment: It looks very hidden indeed.

Comment: @RomainFrancois -- Thanks. Coming from you, I'll take that as an essentially authoritative answer, unless something else gets posted. Appreciate your answering it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a bit of noodling around in `envir.c`, I can get this to work:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

#define HASHSIZE(x)      LENGTH(x)
#define HASHVALUE(x)    TRUELENGTH(x)

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_binding_fun( std::string name, Environment env){
    SEXP symbol = Rf_install( name.c_str() );
    SEXP tab = HASHTAB(env) ;
    SEXP c = PRINTNAME(symbol);

    // finding the hash code for the symbol
    int hashcode = HASHVALUE(c) % HASHSIZE(tab);

    // get the value there from the hash table
    SEXP res = CAR( VECTOR_ELT(tab, hashcode ) ) ;

    return res ;
}
```

Save this into a `.cpp` file, [`sourceCpp`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/Rcpp/html/sourceCpp.html) it and use it with this R code:

```
> makeActiveBinding("x", function() runif(2), .GlobalEnv)
> get_binding_fun("x", .GlobalEnv)
# function ()
# runif(2)
```

Comment: We don't necessarily need `Rcpp` here. I just enjoy using `sourceCpp`