# Get information about a promise without evaluating the promise

Tags: r

In a fresh R session, I created a promise `z`, the vectors `x` and `y`, and a function `obj.info`.

```
delayedAssign("z", logical(5))
x <- 1:100
y <- rnorm(4e3L)
obj.info <- function(envir = .GlobalEnv){
    ls <- ls(envir)
    obj <- sapply(ls, get)
    FUN <- function(x){
        c(type = class(x), length = length(x), size = object.size(x))
    }
    noquote(t(sapply(obj, FUN)))
}
```

---

In RStudio, the Global Environment table is as expected, with the unevaluated promise included.
**This is exactly what I want to duplicate**

---

> [image]

---

A call to `obj.info()` returns the following table.

```
obj.info()
#          type     length size 
# obj.info function 1      13872
# x        integer  100    440  
# y        numeric  4000   32040
# z        logical  5      72
```

The problem is that `z` has been evaluated in the process, and I didn't want that to happen quite yet. All I want is the information about `z`.

At first, I figured `get` was causing this, but evaluation of `z` also occurs if I call `class` on the `ls()` objects before calling `get`. The result I want has

```
# z        promise  0      0
```

for the promised object `z`.

Is the table in the RStudio window something is easily accessible from the console? And if so, can we get it **without evaluating** `z`?  Something like the following `ls.str` table (and others) that can be deparsed would be ideal.

```
capture.output(ls.str())
# [1] "obj.info : function (envir = .GlobalEnv)  "              
# [2] "x :  int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ..."               
# [3] "y :  num [1:4000] -0.277 -0.431 -0.143 -0.218 -0.846 ..."
# [4] "z :  logi [1:5] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE"
```

Or even if there's a way to run this condition through an `if` statement, something like

```
if( x is a promise ) { do not evaluate it, but get its information }
```

I'm running RStudio Version 0.98.994

Comment: According to the [language defintion](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) there is no way in R to tell if something is a promise. Perhaps Rstudio is interacting with R at the C-level to extract that information. What version of RStudio are you using? I can't seem to replicate this behavior

Comment: Fun question. I fear it might not have an answer without breaking out into native code, though.

Comment: @MrFlick - RStudio Version 0.98.994. I'm thinking the RStudio HTML inspector might be useful, maybe?

Comment: I don't speak C++, but [this would seem to be (some of) the relevant code](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/environment/EnvironmentUtils.cpp#L91) from the RStudio sources. Also, I'm pretty sure Konrad's right about having to break into native code to get that info. Finally, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16071526/980833) for a cool answer to a somewhat related question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hadley has a simple Rcpp [implementation of the relevant code in his pryr library](https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/src/promise.cpp).

The relevant code snippet is:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool is_promise2(Symbol name, Environment env) {
  SEXP object = Rf_findVar(name, env);

  return (TYPEOF (object) == PROMSXP);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP promise_code(Symbol name, Environment env) {
  SEXP object = Rf_findVar(name, env);
  return PRCODE(object);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP promise_value(Symbol name, Environment env) {
  SEXP object = Rf_findVar(name, env);
  return PRVALUE(object);
}
```

Here’s how this can be used:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('promise.cpp')
delayedAssign("z", logical(5))
is_promise2('z', environment())
# [1] TRUE
promise_code('y', environment())
# logical(5)
```

However, `sourceCpp` always recompiles the code, which is inefficient. Rcpp sources are normally used as part of a package.

Comment: @Richard Absolutely, that’s what the above code does. It can be loaded in R with `sourceCpp` (it needs the include and `using` statement from the original source though).

Comment: This is great.  +50 if I could.

Comment: @Richard Give them to Hadley. ;-)

Comment: sourceCpp does *not* recompile if the source file has not changed.  Try running it twice in a row to see this.  Also note that pryr is on CRAN so after installing it this is sufficient:  `library(pryr); is_promise("z"); promise_info("z")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck It does recompile in a new R session. That’s what I meant.