# In R: How to perform a str() on multiple files

Tags: r, rstudio

How could I go about performing a `str()` function in R on all of these files loaded in the workspace at the same time? I simply want to export this information out, but in a batch-like process, to a .csv file.  I have over 100 of them, and want to compare one workspace with another to help locate incongruities in data structure and avoid mismatches.

I came painfully close to a solution via [UCLA's R Code Fragment](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/read_multiple.htm), however, they failed to include the instructions for how to form the read.dta function which loops through the files.  That is the part I need help on.

What I have so far:

```
#Define the file path
f <- file.path("C:/User/Datastore/RData")
#List the files in the path
fn <- list.files(f)
#loop through file list, return str() of each .RData file
#write to .csv file with 4 columns (file name, length, size, value)
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example of what I am after (the view from RStudio--it simply lists the Name, Type, Length, Size, and Value of all of the RData Files).  I want to basically replicate this view, but export it out to a .csv.  I am adding the tag to RStudio in case someone might know a way of exporting this table out automatically?  I couldn't find a way to do it.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify what information you want about the files?  `str` returns information about the R object whereas your desired output looks like information about the raw file (e.g. size) which you would get with `file.info`.  You should provide a small example of the desired output.

Comment: if I do `str(filename)`, I should get something like `num [1:409(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...` This is enough for me to know that `filename` is a 1:409 1-dimensional array.  That's all I need. However, with that said, what I really want is something like what is listed in RStudio's Global Environment pane (grid view), if you are familiar with that tool.  I attempted a screen capture but SO wouldn't let me post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually written a function for this already.  I also asked [a question about it, and dealing with promise objects with the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147577/get-information-about-a-promise-without-evaluating-the-promise).  That post might be of some use to you.

The issue with the last column is that `str` is not meant to do anything but print a compact description of objects and therefore I couldn't use it (but that's been changed with recent edits).  This updated function gives a description for the values similar to that of the RStudio table.  The data frames and lists are tricky because their `str` output is more than one line.  This should be good.

```
objInfo <- function(env = globalenv()) 
{
    obj <- mget(ls(env), env)
    out <- lapply(obj, function(x) {
        vals1 <- c(
            Type = toString(class(x)),  
            Length = length(x),  
            Size = object.size(x)
        )
        val2 <- gsub("|^\\s+|'data.frame':\t", "", capture.output(str(x))[1])
        if(grepl("environment", val2)) val2 <- "Environment"
        c(vals1, Value = val2)
    })
    out <- do.call(rbind, out)
    rownames(out) <- seq_len(nrow(out))
    noquote(cbind(Name = names(obj), out))
}
```

And then we can test it out on a few objects..

```
x <- 1:10
y <- letters[1:5]
e <- globalenv()
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = "a")
m <- matrix(1:6)
l <- as.list(1:5)

objInfo()

#   Name    Type        Length Size  Value                          
# 1 df      data.frame  2      1208  1 obs. of  2 variables         
# 2 e       environment 11     56    Environment     
# 3 l       list        5      328   List of 5                      
# 4 m       matrix      6      232   int [1:6, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6       
# 5 objInfo function    1      24408 function (env = globalenv())   
# 6 x       integer     10     88    int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# 7 y       character   5      328   chr [1:5] a b c d e
```

Which is pretty close I guess.  Here's the screen shot of the environment in RStudio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Richard...this is what I was after.  Actually, it's more elaborate than I needed.  I really don't need size. But the objectinfo, type, and length are crucial.  In reading your posts, I realized that simply typing in `ls.str()` within RStudio, printed out the information I wanted!

Comment: Oh, okay.  Well, now you have a new function!  Glad to help

Comment: Never hurts to have a new tool handy.  I actually see some functionality in your code that I can borrow for something else I need, so many thanks!

Comment: Just a note, you might want to add a data frame at the end, as I just used a `noquote` matrix since it was for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function, something like below. And then loop through that function, so you basically write the code for a single dataset

```
library(foreign)
giveSingleDataset <- function( oneFile ) {
  #Read .dta file
  df <- read.dta( oneFile )
  #Give e.g. structure
  s <- ls.str(df)
  #Return what you want
  return(s)
}

#Actually call the function
result <- lapply( fn, giveSingleDataset )
```

Comment: I don't think that would work the way you'd want it to given the way `str` prints its output

Comment: Please see my comment in response to @cdeterman.  Your function gives the structure of the file itself, not the contents of the data file.  What I was looking for was a way of reading in all of the RData files and obtaining their structure, something like `foo_str <- str(foo)` would return `num [1:409(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`